# How to get back to the previous tab I was working on, after closing the latest

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs, vimperator

My tabs:

[1] [2] [3] [4] [**5**] [6] [7] [8] [9] [<s>10</s>] [**11**]

### Scenario

If you're a Firefox user you know that

if you have **10** tabs open and say you're in the tab **#5**. If you open a new tab which will become **#11** in order and search something, after you finish and close this #11 tab Firefox will direct you the the last active tab you were in which is **#5**.

***Using Vimperator***

You won't get the similar effect. In the same scenario, while you're in tab **#5** you can go <kbd>t</kbd> and search for something which will lead to opening a tab at **#11**. Now you press <kbd>d</kbd> and where you are now ? **#10**

and you need to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> all the way back to #5.

So in this case I am looking for one of these solutions.

1. to be able to open a tab straight after the current tab (which closing it will capital D will put me back to my active tab)
2. a way to close a tab and being brought back to the last active tab that I worked on.

Will appreciate it if somebody got a solution for this.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you know the solution (point 2): use the default firefox shorcut, i.ed use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and don't use <kbd>d</kbd> !

Comment: Tobe frank, I thought this shortcut is overwritten by Vimperator. This means I can allocate `Ctrl+w` to the `d` key and happy days... I appreciate you answer man.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to vimperator and i was looking into this question. The better way to do it is to use **:q**. This way you can go back to the previously active tab without missing vim's experience

Comment: This is actually exactly right. Thanks for your reply and letting us know pal.

Answer (score 1):

Remap `d` to `C-w` by adding

```
map d <C-w>
```

to your `~/.vimperatorrc`.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Cheers :)